# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function___

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I encountered some difficulties in running this code that I am not sure what's wrong with this.
[This is the error information given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0H62.png)

```
    SELECT LD.PROVIDER_NUM,
           LD.LOCALDOCTORFIRSTNAME,
           LD.LOCALDOCTORLASTNAME,
           LD.LOCALDOCTORPHONENUM,
           A.ADDRESS_STREET,
           A.POSTCODE, 
           PA.APPOINTMENTDATE,
           COUNT(PA.PROVIDER_NUM) AS PATIENTREFERRED
      FROM PATIENTAPPOINTMENT PA, LOCALDOCTORS LD, ADDRESS A 
     WHERE PA.PROVIDER_NUM = LD.PROVIDER_NUM
       AND LD.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID
       AND PA.APPOINTMENTDATE >=ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-6);
```

Comment: [Asked many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+ORA-00937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use GROUP BY clause in your query coz you are using other columns with aggregate function `COUNT`. Also, Always use the proper explicit joins -

```
SELECT LD.PROVIDER_NUM,
       LD.LOCALDOCTORFIRSTNAME,
       LD.LOCALDOCTORLASTNAME,
       LD.LOCALDOCTORPHONENUM,
       A.ADDRESS_STREET,
       A.POSTCODE, 
       PA.APPOINTMENTDATE,
       COUNT(PA.PROVIDER_NUM) AS PATIENTREFERRED
  FROM PATIENTAPPOINTMENT PA
  JOIN LOCALDOCTORS LD ON PA.PROVIDER_NUM = LD.PROVIDER_NUM
  JOIN ADDRESS A ON LD.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID
 WHERE PA.APPOINTMENTDATE >=ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-6)
 GROUP BY LD.PROVIDER_NUM,
          LD.LOCALDOCTORFIRSTNAME,
          LD.LOCALDOCTORLASTNAME,
          LD.LOCALDOCTORPHONENUM,
          A.ADDRESS_STREET,
          A.POSTCODE, 
          PA.APPOINTMENTDATE;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. The code works well, but it shows me no rows selected.

Comment: Sorry, I have just realized that the data in the table has a problem. Thank you for the solution